# Moving data from firebase realtime database to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on chat program and for its database, I use firebase realtime database. But I can get access to firebase realtime database only by using vpn server. But to get access to firestore I do not need that. So I want that my code to write data to firestore instead of writing it to realtime database.

For example here in my register activity:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        String DeviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                        String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_user_id);
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.removeValue();
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.child("user_name").setValue(name);
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.child("user_status").setValue("Ulgamda user");
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.child("user_image").setValue("default_profile");
                        storeUserDefaultDatabaseReference.child("user_thumb_image").setValue("default_profile")
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            Log.e("Database error","Error saving data", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                          "Error",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                 }
            });
```

I want this code to write to firestore. Is there some code to do that? Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the official documentation and ask another question if something else comes up.